# checking image with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if image exists with a javascript code

```
function imExist2(imurl, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() { callback(true); };
    img.onerror = function() { callback(false); };
    img.src = imurl;
}
```

using the code

```
function imExist(imNr) {
    var imUrl = 'default.png';
    var imageUrl = 'image' + imNr + '.png';
    var imageUrl = imExist2(imageUrl, function(exists) {
        //problem is that the inner function imExist2 is running too late
        //after if all other javascript have runned to end
        if(exists) imUrl = imageUrl;
        alert(2);
    });
    return imUrl;
}
```

And how do I get alerts in sequence "1", "2" and "3", not "1", "3" and "2". I want like in procedural paradigm function imExist() returns correctly true or false if correct image exist correspondingly?

```
alert(1);
(imExist(23));
alert(3);
```

Thank you

Comment: Image loading is asynchronous, you can't do it like in procedural paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without callback.

The first thing you must learn if you want to program in JavaScript is to deal with asynchronous actions and events.

You must put your `alert(3)` in the callback using the `imExist2` function :

```
alert(1);
imExist2('image' + 23 + '.png', function(ok){
    alert(3);
    alert('ok:' + ok);
});
```

As an aside, your life will be better if you use [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log) instead of `alert`.

Comment: No, i want such simple solution that i can use like e.g $('#divid').html('<img src="'+imExist(34)+'" />');.

Comment: @user2301515 I said it : **You can't**. use  `imExist(34, function(ok){ if (ok) $('#divid').html('<img src=someurl"/>') });`